# HTMLタグをエスケープせずに表示したい

Tags: html, node.js, html5, pug

Node.js + Express + Pugでサイトを構築しています。

サーバ側のNode.jsで次のようにプログラムを書いて

```
const nico="<a href=\"http://www.nicovideo.jp/\">test</a>";

res.render('index', {
        nico:nico
});
```

pugで次のように受け取ると

```
p(style="white-space:pre;") #{nico}
```

htmlで以下のようになってしまいます。

```
<p style="white-space:pre;">&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.nicovideo.jp/&quot;&gt;test&lt;/a&gt;</p>
```

実際にはhtmlを以下のように生成したいです。

```
<p style="white-space:pre;"><a href="http://www.nicovideo.jp/">test</a>></<a href="http://www.nicovideo.jp/">test</a></p>
```

`p(style="white-space:pre;")`を使わなければ、HTMLタグがエスケープされず
そのまま表示されるのですが、`p(style="white-space:pre;")`を使わないと改行が反映されず、長い文を書く時に改行されてない表示になってしまうので、`p(style="white-space:pre;")`は残したいと考えています。

どうしたら解決できますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。

```
p(style="white-space:pre;")!=nico
```

とすれば良ようです。